# how to convert column dtypes for DateTime and Time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that includes columns with time and Date as **objects dtypes**

I want to convert the columns to **Time and DateTime dtypes**

When i try to convert it display the below error for the Date:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

## code:

import pandas as pd

```
df=pd.DataFrame( {
    'time': ['22:00:00', 'nan', '00:45:00', 'nan'],
    'date': ['2020-09-30T00:00:00+03:00','0001-01-01T00:00:00+02:22','2020-10-01T00:00:00+03:00','0001-01-01T00:00:00+02:22']
     })            
df["date"]=df["date"].fillna("00/00/0000")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],errors='coerce',format='%d%m%y')
                     
df["time"]=df["time"].fillna("00:00:00")
df["time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["time"].str.strip())
        
print(df.info())
```

How to fix this error??

Comment: Your dataframe doesn't seem to work. the length of the time column is longer than that of the date column. This should give you a value error ```ValueError: arrays must all be same length```. Also empty string will are not na values

Comment: @Horla.li sorry for this mistake i correct it and its now same length

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the code:

- when you create the dataframe the date column has one less value than the time column
- the `fillna` method would just replace Null (or nan) values not empty strings
- "00/00/0000" is not a valid date for python's date time
- your date format is slightly off, you are missing the `/` separating the fields and I believe that your dates are with month before day (see "09/30/2020")

Here a proposal that fixes those errors:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": ["10:00:00 PM", None, "12:45:00 AM", None, "1:00:00 AM"],
        "date": ["9/30/2020", "10/1/2020", None, "10/1/2020", None],
    }
)
df["date"] = df["date"].fillna("01/01/1970")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce", format="%m/%d/%Y")

df["time"] = df["time"].fillna("00:00:00")
df["time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["time"].str.strip())

print(df.info())
```

This code runs and the final df has no null values.

Comment: can i fill the nan values with value that is before insted of a predefine  value ??

like :  "10:00:00 PM" , "10:00:00 PM"

Comment: yes. You would need to specify the pad metod to fillna `fillna(method="pad")`

Comment: i will edit my question and add the dataframe as its displayed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for.

To answer the question:
`I want to convert the columns to Time and DateTime dtypes` -- There is nothing like Time datatype in pandas.

Closest we can get is `Timedelta` or `datetime` object.

**One option is below to get the `time object`**

filled the time as per the requirement.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.time.ffill()
```

**Output**

```
    time        date
0   22:00:00    2020-09-30 00:00:00+03:00
1   22:00:00    NaT
2   00:45:00    2020-10-01 00:00:00+03:00
3   00:45:00    NaT
```

**Second Option is Timedelta**

This is little bit annoying as it add `0 days` at the start.
To extract only the time from it we will have to convert it to string.(Not sure if that is the requirement)

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.time).ffill().astype(str).str.split().str[-1]
```

**Output**

```
    time        date
0   22:00:00    2020-09-30 00:00:00+03:00
1   22:00:00    NaT
2   00:45:00    2020-10-01 00:00:00+03:00
3   00:45:00    NaT
```